# How to make menu/instruction screen in winforms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a very simple application and would need to have a menu screen in the beginning.

However I do not know what is the best way:

1. Use different Form? But then both can be independently sized which I do not want
2. Use (modal?) Custom Control in the Main form that disappears once the "Run" is selected.
3. In the `Application.Run` execute the Menu, finish and then execute the app itself? Not sure if there will be any problems with that.
4. Any Other options?

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: Windows Applications in .NET are called `WinForms` not `Forms`.

Comment: Considering WinForms is merely a shortened and concatenated version of the words Windows Forms I'd say Mocco can use the word Forms as much as they want as long as it's clear from context what they mean. Which it is. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all; set up a view controller. One central class that you can ask what view to display. This will save you a few issues down the line.

Second there are several ways to approach this. Personally I don't like having many free-floating forms (even though they are displayed one at the time). If you use forms then consider setting them as MDI children for the main form. The ViewController can take care of maintenance like setting as MDI child, show, maximize, go to top, remove minimize button, etc.

Alternatively you can use user controls that you initialize and put on the screen.

From what I read your main concern is how to control when a screen is displayed, for whatever reason. If you hook up events such as Form_Close to the ViewController you can put the logic there.

Answer (score 1):

Create a User Control for each "screen". Put an instance of each User Control onto your Form with `Dock = Fill`. Hide them as necessary. Of course you will need a MenuScreen user control which will be `Visible = true` initially. When an item on the menu is clicked, simple `Visible = false` for MenuScreen and `Visible = true` for the required User Control. When "return to menu" is clicked, hide the User Control and show the MenuScreen.